# Conditional execution of XSL template

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xalan

Hi I am faced with the problem where I want my template match to only execute when a particular condition is met in a another XPATH

This is my input XML

```
<Items OrderReference="" TransactionId="">
    <Item Type="OPEN" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
        FirstDate="2021-12-10" IgnorePromised="N"
        IgnoreUnpromised="N" ItemID="Item1"
        LastShipDate="2022-01-10" OrganizationCode="YK"
        ProductClass="GOOD" TotalRequiredQty="1.00" UnitOfMeasure="EACH">
        <Supplies>
            <Supply FirstDate="2021-12-10" IsUnplannedSupply="N"
                LastShipDate="2023-12-10" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
                Quantity="100.00" Segment="" SegmentType=""
                ShipNode="YKDC"  Track="Y"/>
        </Supplies>
    </Item>
    <Item DemandType="OPEN_ORDER" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
        FirstDate="2021-12-10" IgnorePromised="N"
        IgnoreUnpromised="N" ItemID="Item2" LastShipDate="2022-01-10"
        OrganizationCode="YK" ProductClass="GOOD"
        TotalRequiredQty="1.00" UnitOfMeasure="EACH">
        <Supplies>
            <Supply FirstDate="2021-12-10" IsUnplannedSupply="N"
                LastShipDate="2023-12-10" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
                Quantity="152.00" Segment="" SegmentType=""
                ShipNode="BDDC" SoftAssignedQty="0.00" TagNumber="" Track="Y"/>
            <Supply FirstDate="2021-12-10" IsUnplannedSupply="N"
                LastShipDate="2023-12-10" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
                Quantity="100.00" Segment="" SegmentType=""
                ShipNode="YKDC" SoftAssignedQty="0.00" TagNumber="" Track="Y"/>
           
        </Supplies>
    </Item>
    <Item DemandType="OPEN_ORDER" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
        FirstDate="2021-12-10" IgnorePromised="N"
        IgnoreUnpromised="N" ItemID="Item3" LastShipDate="2022-01-10"
        OrganizationCode="YK" ProductClass="GOOD"
        TotalRequiredQty="1.00" UnitOfMeasure="EACH">
        <Supplies>
            <Supply FirstDate="2021-12-10" IsUnplannedSupply="N"
                LastShipDate="2023-12-10" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
                Quantity="952.00" Segment="" SegmentType=""
                ShipNode="BDDC" SoftAssignedQty="0.00" TagNumber="" Track="Y"/>
            <Supply FirstDate="2021-12-10" IsUnplannedSupply="N"
                LastShipDate="2023-12-10" EnterpriseCode="XXXX"
                Quantity="776.00" Segment="" SegmentType=""
                ShipNode="YKDC" SoftAssignedQty="0.00" TagNumber="" Track="Y"/>
           
        </Supplies>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I want to zero out the Quantity for ShipNode BDDC only when there exist a node where YKDC is the only child for a particular item and all other items have both BDDC and YKDC present.

Here is my solution so far

````
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xalan" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/Items/Item/Supplies/Supply[@ShipNode='BDDC']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Supply) and ../Supply[@ShipNode='YKDC']">
                <xsl:attribute name="Quantity">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'0.00'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am unable to test my another main condition for  Item1 where availability is only on YKDC.

Please excuse for long and convoluted question.
````

Answer (score 0):

A long and convoluted match pattern to check all that and change the Quantity is hopefully

```
<xsl:template match="/Items[Item[not (*[2]) and not(*/*[2]) and Supplies/Supply[@ShipNode='YKDC']] and Item[*/*[2]][Supplies/Supply[@ShipNode='YKDC'] and Supplies/Supply[@ShipNode='BDDC']]]/Item/Supplies/Supply[@ShipNode ='BDDC']/@Quantity">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```